# Issues with hand Clapping gesture

Tags: c#, kinect

This my code for clapping hand gesture ,i use the result to set a robotic arm end effector to a 3d location for every clap)
i want the event handler to  trigger just once for every clap gesture,
and reset  for another clap  gesture. but when i clap and my hands are close together, my event handler keeps firing!! please how do i correct this issue. could i use a reset method or something

[hand clap code]

```
float previousDistance = 0.0f;
    private void MatchClappingGesture(Skeleton skeleton)
    {
        if (skeleton == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {

            float currentDistance = GetJointDistance(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight], skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft]);
            {


                if (currentDistance < 0.1f && previousDistance > 0.1f )
                {

                   if (this.GestureRecognized != null)
                    {

                        this.GestureRecognized(this, new  GestureEventArgs(RecognitionResult.Success));
                        previousDate = DateTime.Now;
                   }

                }
                previousDistance = currentDistance;

            }


        }

    }
```

this is where i call the event handler

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
            kinect.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Could not find Kinect Camera: " + ex.Message);
        }

        kinect.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
        kinect.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution1280x960Fps12);
        kinect.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters()
        {
            Correction = 0.5f,
            JitterRadius = 0.05f,
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.05f,
            Prediction = 0.5f,
            Smoothing = 0.5f
        });
        kinect.AllFramesReady += Kinect_SkeletonAllFramesReady;


        recognitionEngine = new GestureRecognitionEngine();
        armEngine = new ArmControllerEngine();

        recognitionEngine.GestureRecognized += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(recognitionEngine_GestureRecognized);
    }
```

event handler fires here

```
         void recognitionEngine_GestureRecognized(object sender,      

         GestureEventArgs e)
         { 
         //armEngine.setArm(raMove,port,servoId);   
         MessageBox.Show("HI");

        }
```

the message box prints multiple time instead of just once!!please help

Answer (score 0):

You must bear in mind that Kinect's measurements have a degree of inaccuracy. Also, in certain cases (like when the hands are together!!) that inaccuracy increases greatly, and the detected joint positions start jumping all over the place. Try it with the SDK's provided skeleton viewer and you'll see. This is often mitigated by using smoothing algorithms, but in your case that might not be the most adequate solution. Try increasing the distance you are using to detect the gesture, give it some 20cm or so (btw, what does your `GetJointDistance` returns? Meters? Then give it 0.2)

Comment: The  `GetJointDistance`  just returns the distance between the hands. I have no problem with the distance. i just want the method to reset once the gesture is detected...so that it does not fire an event untill i clap again. but presently, if i clap once and keep my hands together, the events keeps repeating.

Comment: Guys please help out!!

Comment: I was going to suggest adding a flag to avoid repeating the event, but the previousDistance variable you have should take care of that. Did you try, as I suggested, simply increasing the distance specified in your test, from 0.1 to 0.2, or perhaps a little more?

Comment: it finally worked!! thanks your tips were helpful Bro

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but if your problem is solved, could you accept one of the two answers? You know, just so it doesn't appear on the "Unanswered" section, and so other users can find it helpful too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
           void wait(int a) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) ;

    }

         int count = 0;


    void recognitionEngine_GestureRecognized(object sender, GestureEventArgs  e)
     {
        wait(3);
         clapShow();

     }
     //clap method
     void clapShow() 
      {

       count += 1;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Gesture Capture Within >> " + time.Millisecond.ToString()  +   " milli Seconds");

        }
        count = 0 ; 
        } 
}
```

I called the message box as a method every 3millsecs `wait(3)` so that slows down the the event handler.
Then set the count to "1" before a gesture then back to "0"after every clap gesture and it works pretty well!!
Note!.... The `wait(X)` method i created a simple loop that counts down to the value X. It can be any value based on the level of sensitivity level one desires. Thanks jose!!
i hope this helps someone..